# What is purpose of type on the constructor side of Java collection creation?

Tags: java, collections, variable-declaration

What is purpose of re-specifying the type on the right / constructor side of a Java Collection declaration + instantiation?

For example, how is

```
List<MyClass> a = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

different / better / worse than

```
List<MyClass> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

My understanding is the the second form became legal in Java 7, but I still see a lot of examples in Java 7 and 8 where the first form is used.

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki. I did lot of searching on stack overflow for an answer before posting, but did not know/use the term 'diamond operator'. Had not heard that terminology before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not worse or different. It is the same.

A new and easy way introduced by compiler to reduce human effort of defining of type.